# ¿Por qué mi página web no se visualiza en celulares?

Tags: html, android, css

Hice un mini proyecto que anda normal en pc (Firefox y Chrome) pero al pasarlo a mi celular y visualizarlo tanto en Samsung Internet Browser y Chrome solo me muestra el contenido del html (texto, imagenes...) pero no aplica el CSS como debería. Verifiqué los media queries y no noto ningún problema, asimismo considero que el viewport fue correctamente establecido ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué sucede esto? Uso un max-width ya que el proyecto es RWD

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  main .column {
    -webkit-box-flex: 100%;
        -ms-flex: 100%;
            flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  main .tweetCard {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
  }
  main .tweetCard .section1 div {
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  main .tweetCard .section2 p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  main .tweetCard .section2 .fecha {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
  main .tweetCard .section3 .retweet, main .tweetCard .section3 .like, main .tweetCard .section3 .cta button {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Deberías incluir todo tu html, solo estas incluyendo la etiqueta meta, es para poder probar la pagina. y pues en tu CSS no veo problema, tus reglas deberían aplicarse de 360px de tamaño de pantalla hacia abajo.

Comment: Puede ser que el dispositivo en el que estás visualizando el html tenga un ancho mayor a 360px

Comment: Verificaste las rutas a los archivos css. Prueba con esto abre un servidor local ingresa ahí tu web y accede desde tu celular a esa web.

Comment: 1. Intentaré montar un servidor local, comentaré al rato si funcionó. 2. Por si acaso mi celular es un Samsung J7 Neo, y tiene un ancho menor a 360. Pero ese no puede ser el error ya que tengo media queries configurados para un width de mayor tamaño

Comment: Habilité el servidor local y oh sorpresa si funciona, gracias DavElsanto. Ya sabía que los media queries no podían ser el problema, pero ¿por qué si me acepta al montar el servidor y no al tratar de leer los archivos desde el mismo celular?

Hay una app en la play store llamada TrebEdit, es un editor de archivos html, css... dicha app posee un visor como si de un navegador se tratase. Con este visor no había problemas para leer el html y css. Es por esta razón que pensé que quizás había algo mal en el código.

Comment: Estas cargando la url dentro de un WebView ?@Juan

Comment: @Jorgesys TrebEdit tiene uno y ese sí me reconocía correctamente los archivos. Pero los navegadores convencionales no.